# How to add a word after my root URL for every request?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, drupal-6

Consider

```
http://localhost/MyProject/
```

This is the root url

When accessing this i want to alter the url to

```
http://localhost/MyProject/Apps/
```

The url should look like above but should execute

```
http://localhost/MyProject/index.php
```

That is i just want to add the word 'Apps' to the url. There is no folder named 'Apps'...

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost/MyProject/index/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http:localhost/index.php [R=301,L]
```

hope this will help... coz I did not try it on my local environment.

Comment: `HTTP_HOST` will only match against the domain (localhost) not the full URI. And a 301 Redirect will change the URL to the destination, which is what the original poster wants to not do, no?

Answer (score 1):

You need a Mod_Rewrite addition to your `.htaccess` file (in your `MyProject` folder):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule /? Apps/ [R=301,L] # Force people to the "Apps" folder 
  RewriteRule Apps/?$ index.php # Make "Apps" load the index
</IfModule>
```

Comment: There is no Apps folder man..I just want to add the word Apps to the url

Comment: Right, that is what that line does. You don't ever want someone to enter `http://localhost/MyProject/` on the address bar, you want them to enter `http://localhost/MyProject/Apps`. The first line rewrites the URL for people if in fact they do type in the first. The second rewrite rule then makes `http://localhost/MyProject/Apps` not trigger a 404 error (since Apps doesn't exist), and instead loads `index.php` (but keeps the URL the same)

Comment: @MidnightLighting - if client enter the address as http://localhost/MyProject/  what will happen ?

Comment: `/MyProject` and `/MyProject/` should both be redirected to `/MyProject/Apps`. I added a questionmark to the first RewriteRule to catch that first case as well as the second.

Comment: @MidnightLighting - but it showing "The page isn't redirecting properly
...Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."

Comment: Then you have something else going on in your server (another conflicting rule?) that's causing it to not work.